# Pandas pick previous column value of a corresponding nan value

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my dataframe assuming this is in sequence with a row number added in

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({'unit': [256, 256, 256,256,256,256,256], 'date': [np.nan,np.nan,'2020-04-09', '2020-04-09', '2020-04-09',np.nan,'2020-04-10'], 'status': ['CMP','CMP','A','A','A','A','A'],'comp_date': ['2020-04-08','2020-04-09','2020-04-16', '2020-04-16', '2020-04-16','2020-04-11','2020-04-16'],'ven': [np.nan,np.nan,'T', 'T', 'T',np.nan,'T']})
```

[image]

I am looking for new column(new_date) by looking historical latest comp_date records whose 'ven'is null

Expected output:

[image]

I tried with below logic but its time taking.

```
df_final=pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(len(df_n)+1):
    df_test=df_n[df_n['n_row_num']==x]
    df_test3=df[df['row_num']<df_test['row_num'].tail(1).iloc[0]]
    df_test['final_date']=df_test3.loc[df_test3['row_num'].idxmax()].comp_date
    df_final=pd.concat([df_final, df_test], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

looking for some better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the last `NaN` with the following dates, then `groupby` and `apply` custom function which assign directly:

```
s = (df["ven"].isnull()&df["ven"].shift(-1).eq("T")).cumsum()

def func(d):
    d.loc[d["ven"].notnull(), "new_date"] = d.loc[d["ven"].isnull(), "comp_date"].iat[-1]
    return d

print (df.groupby(s).apply(func))

   unit        date status   comp_date  ven    new_date
0   256         NaN    CMP  2020-04-08  NaN         NaN
1   256         NaN    CMP  2020-04-09  NaN         NaN
2   256  2020-04-09      A  2020-04-16    T  2020-04-09
3   256  2020-04-09      A  2020-04-16    T  2020-04-09
4   256  2020-04-09      A  2020-04-16    T  2020-04-09
5   256         NaN      A  2020-04-11  NaN         NaN
6   256  2020-04-10      A  2020-04-16    T  2020-04-11
```

Comment: This would assign the same date for all new columns. I'll update the images for better understanding